# "Windows key + R" is no longer working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, windows-key

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is no longer working. It was working a while back, and it still works in the Windows 7 VM I'm running on the same machine.

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *does* work, but some other shortcuts do not work.

I tried solutions from a similar problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/182829/win-key-arrow-keyboard-shortcuts-no-longer-working) but they did not work.

I do not have the registry values suggested at this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/412484/windows-key-shortcuts-stopped-working).

Comment: It's called "Sticky Keys" it was likely enabled when you spammed accidentally a Key combination there was a prompt displayed also.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/65062/window-key-commands-not-working-in-windows-7?rq=1), I pressed every key on the keyboard a few times then it started working again. I am not sure why some hotkeys worked some did not work but it looks like I had a key that was stuck.

Comment: Maybe you literally had *sticky keys*.

Comment: LOL. I have had problems with the ctrl key getting stuck in the past too.